# Marquee progress bar and PM_SETMARQUEE being ignored in VB6

Tags: vb6, progress-bar, common-controls

I've just tried setting up a scrolling marquee progress bar in one of my VB6 applications, and while it seems to switch into marquee mode, the automatic timer (set via [`PBM_SETMARQUEE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) either fails or is ignored.

- I have an appropriate visual style manifest.
- I have called `InitCommonControls` in the form's `Initialize` event.
- I am using the v5 SP2 common controls.
- The project is compiled.
- I have set the `PBS_MARQUEE` style via `SetWindowLong` and confirmed it has applied.
- The `PBM_SETMARQUEE` message returns 1.

The results:

- If I minimise and restore the window it progresses one step.
- If I set `.Value` it progresses one step.
- If I send `PBM_STEPIT` it progresses one step.
- If I send `PBM_SETMARQUEE` it sits there doing nothing.

If I don't pass the initial `PBM_SETMARQUEE` enable message, then the minimise/restore doesn't cause it to progress suggesting the timer is the problem.

This is the same issue discussed in [this thread from 2006](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?462116-Marquee-Progressbar)

Does anyone have any deeper insight as to why the VB wrapper is dropping the `PBM_SETMARQUEE` message or the associated timer events and why I need to do it "manually"?

```
Option Explicit

Private Const GWL_STYLE = (-16)
Private Const PBS_MARQUEE = &H8
Private Const WM_USER = &H400
Private Const PBM_STEPIT = WM_USER + 5
Private Const PBM_SETMARQUEE = WM_USER + 10

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
  'Set the marquee style
  Dim Style As Long
  Style = GetWindowLong(ProgressBar1.hWnd, GWL_STYLE)
  Style = Style Or PBS_MARQUEE
  SetWindowLong ProgressBar1.hWnd, GWL_STYLE, Style
  'Set automatic marquee mode
  SendMessage ProgressBar1.hWnd, PBM_SETMARQUEE, 1, ByVal 0&
End Sub
```

This is needed to make it progress.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  SendMessage ProgressBar1.hWnd, PBM_STEPIT, 0, ByVal 0&
End Sub
```

Comment: [This post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.vb.general.discussion/6vaRAT5JJbo/_YXLbYfo9KsJ) suggests that it is OS specific. I've replaced the `PBM_SETMARQUEE` with an external timer periodically sending `PBM_STEPIT`.

Comment: You can also just set `.Value = 0` each Timer tick instead of sending a message.

Comment: Same issue also described in 2007 here: http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/SPSBlog/CommentView,guid,9e494312-e24a-4063-ae8c-ec194db8549a.aspx